# JavaScript "+ if" inside variable

Tags: javascript

I have a variable with a long chain of + operators connecting a number of different variables and strings. It looks something like this:

```
var someVariable = 'this'+ variable1 + 'something' + variable2 + 'somethingElse';
```

However I need to add a another variable on the end which is conditionally set like this:

```
var conditionalVar;

if (meetCondition) {
  conditionalVar = "something";
}

var someVariable = 'this'+ variable1 + 'something' + variable2 + 'somethingElse' + if (typeof conditionalVar !== "undefined") { conditionalVar };
```

However this gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if " in the console.

Are there any solutions to this? I want to place `conditionalVar` in `someVariable` only if it contains a value.

Also I don't really want to bloat the code by doing this (I have a load of if statements prior to it.

```
var conditionalVar;
var someVariable;

    if (meetCondition) {
      conditionalVar = "something";
      var someVariable = 'this'+ variable1 + 'something' + variable2 + 'somethingElse' + conditionalVar;
    } else {
      conditionalVar = "something";
      var someVariable = 'this'+ variable1 + 'something' + variable2 + 'somethingElse';
     }
```

Comment: instead of using if, use conditional statement such as: var someVariable = "a" + (conditionalVar ? conditionalVar : "");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change this condition with conditional operator

```
var someVariable = 'this'+ variable1 + 'something' + variable2 + 'somethingElse' + ((typeof conditionalVar !== "undefined")? conditionalVar :'');
```

Comment: Why not `... conditionVar === undefined? conditionVar : ''` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var someVariable = 'this'+ variable1 + 'something' + variable2 + 'somethingElse' + (conditionalVar ? conditionalVar : "");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/SaHF6/)**

Answer (score 1):

use ternary operator instead of `if` in that statement, `if` as a part of other statement is not valid in javascript ( but may be valid in other languages like Python )

```
var name='John';
var greet =  "Hello ," + (( typeof(name) == "undefined" ) ? "User" : name) ;
   // greet is now "Hello , John"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a ternary operation or a real if statement.

```
var someVariable = 'foobar' + ((typeof conditionalVar !== "undefined") ? conditionalVar : '');
```

or

```
if(typeof conditionalVar !== "undefined") {
    someVariable += conditionalVar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var conditionalVar;



var someVariable = 'this'+ variable1 + 'something' + variable2 + 'somethingElse';

if (meetCondition) {
  conditionalVar = "something";
  someVariable += conditionalVar ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the value of *conditionVar* is dependent on the condition, then the condition should be used with the [*conditional operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12):

```
... + (meetCondition? something : '');
```

which removes the need for *conditionVar* entirely.